# ConditionalExpression Limiting Domain

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I came across a problem when evaluating the following integral:

$\int_0^t \sqrt{9 x^4+1} \, dx$

Now, when I evaluate that, I get

```
ConditionalExpression[t Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/4, 5/4, -9 t^4], t >= 0]
```

The issue is if t is negative.  If I do this 
$\int_0^{-5} \sqrt{9 x^4+1} \, dx$ I get

```
-5 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/4, 5/4, -5625]
```

That seems okay, since it's a number.  However, if I do this $\int_0^t \sqrt{9 x^4+1} \, dx\text{/.}t\to -5$
I get "Undefined".

The issue is that I need to keep t symbolic, but still be able to use negative numbers later.

I don't understand why t must be positive, especially since Mathematica seems to be able to compute it when it's negative.  Does anyone know why this is happening, or what I can do to fix it?

EDIT:

I'm actually looking for a general solution for any function.  This code is being used to calculate arc length of any function (in this case, x^3).  This is just an example of it not working.

Here is my actual code:

```
baseFunction = Function[x,x^3]
secondFunction = Sin
r[t_] = FullSimplify[p0[t] + norm[t]*a*secondFunction[b*Integrate[Sqrt[1 + Derivative[1][baseFunction][x]^2], {x, 0, t}]], Element[t, Reals]]
```

p0 and norm are 2D vector functions, and a and b are constants.  I want to be able to use any function for baseFunction, though, which is why I need a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Integrate[Sqrt[9 x^4 + 1], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> {t < 0}]

t Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/4, 5/4, -9 t^4]
```

which can be evaluated at t=-5 to give

```
% //. t -> -5
-5 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/4, 5/4, -5625]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Assuming, in order to obtain the solution first

```
Assuming[Element[t, Reals] && t > 0,Integrate[Sqrt[9 x^4 + 1], {x, 0, t}]] /. t -> -5
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can't answer now why `t` has to be assumed positive, but can subs a negative value for it later without looking more into this. But the above seems to do what you wanted. Actually the above used `t>0` and not `t>=0` and it worked.

Comment: Thanks!  The only issue, though, and I probably should have mentioned this in the OP, is that the function to integrate over can be anything.  This particular example is finding arc length of the function x^3.  So I'm actually looking for a general solution to this problem.

Comment: Edited the OP to give an example